# php 7.1.1 drivers for SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using php drivers to conect a XAMPP (v3.2.2) with an MSSQL 2008 server.
The drivers have been downloaded from github (https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql).

On two Win10 Proffesional PC's the connection with SQL is established without any problem.

On a third PC (Win10 Home) the connection is not established. 
I am trying to figure out if there is a Win10 version compatibilitty issue or if there is another something else   ???

Comment: Well do let us know when you find out.

Comment: Do you have all the [ODBC Drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420) installed and are there any verbose messages in the `Event Viewer` ?

Comment: @Dan...finally it was the ODBC Drivers! I had installed them few days ago... but I suppose with the continuous installations and trials probably something was conflicting. Installing again the ODBC drivers the problem was solved! (In the Event viewer there were no messages!) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Most problems are solved by (re)installing a fresh package of Microsoft's ODBC Drivers.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420